# plantuml background color for text blocks within note

Tags: plantuml

I am trying set background color for specific blocks of multiline text within Plantuml sequence diagram "note".

For example, in the below snippet for Plantuml Sequence diagram, how to apply a specific background color for `<code>` part of the note?

```
participant Alice
note left of Alice
    This text with default color.
    <code>
    println("Hello Alice")
    println("Welcome to Wonderland!")
    </code>
end note
```

So far I could only find `<back:color>` but it doesn't seem to work on multiline text.

Answer (score 5):

There may be a cleaner way with the new `<style>` features, but here's a somewhat kludgy solution using a preprocessor function

```
@startuml
!function $my_code($fgcolor, $bgcolor)
!return "<color:"+$fgcolor+"><back:"+$bgcolor+"><size:14><b><font:monospaced>"
!endfunction
participant Alice
note left of Alice
    This text with default color.
    $my_code(white, black)println("Hello Alice")
    $my_code(yellow, blue)println("Welcome to Wonderland!")
end note
@enduml
```

[image]

Note that since PlantUML doesn't require closing ending tags (new line turns them all off) this works.

Comment: thanks for bright me up many useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution for your problem might be a skin parameter:

```
@startuml
skinparam NoteBackgroundColor red
participant Alice
note left of Alice
    This text with default color.
    <code>
    println("Hello Alice")
    println("Welcome to Wonderland!")
    </code>
end note
@enduml
```

see for a full list e.g `java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar plantuml.jar -language` and the available documentation about skinparameters.

Note: OP only wants to have the `code` part in another color and this solution gives the complete `note` a background color.

Comment: That would set backgound color for the whole note. I would like to highlight only the "code" part of the note in the example.